# Count child DIVs + add class

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following bit of code to display thumbnails on a page:

`<div id="gallery">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="" />
     </div>
 </div>`

This will loop to show 15 .thumbnail DIVs.

I would like to attach a class of ".last" to the 5th DIV and the 10th DIV. And for the 11-15th DIVs a class of ".bottom-last".

I understand that this is the way to go: http://api.jquery.com/length/ but cannot figure out a way to get the count and then attached the class.

Any pointers?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way if you don't mind the syntax. (of course, you could easily use a traditional `if()` statement as well)

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/bBgTs/1/

```
$('#gallery .thumbnail').addClass(function(i) {
    return ((i == 4 || i == 9) && 'last') || (i > 9 && 'bottom-last');
});
```

Comment: +1, i like this too (plus i used `or` instead of `||` in mine, and just saw it while looking at your answer)

Comment: @Gaby - I didn't even notice that you had `or`! :o) If you're doing minor corrections though, you have `addclass` instead of `addClass`. I figured OP would get the overall point. :o)

Comment: This works very well for me, thanks very much Patrick, excellent stuff!

Answer (score 4):

use the each method which passes the index as a parameter..

```
$('#gallery .thumbnail').each( function(idx){
if (idx==4 || idx==9)
  $(this).addClass('last');
if (idx > 9)
  $(this).addClass('bottom-last');
} );
```

note the numbers are 1 minus what you want, because the index is zero-based

Comment: @scott, it should be 9 because it is zero-based, but you are correct. I had messed the numbers in my answer.. updated. thanks.

Comment: Yep, this works very well, I went with Patrick's answer as it seems a simpler solution, but this worked just as well for me. But thanks for this solution, very appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".thumbnail:eq(4), .thumbnail:eq(9)").addClass("last");
$(".thumbnail:gt(9)").addClass("bottom-last");
```